# How to try-except an illegal matrix operation due to singularity in NumPy

Tags: python, numpy, linear-algebra

In NumPy, I'm trying to use `linalg` to compute matrix inverses at each step of a Newton-Raphson scheme (the problem size is small intentionally so that we can invert analytically computed Hessian matrices). However, after I get far along towards convergence, the Hessian gets close to singular.

Is there any method within NumPy that lets me test whether a matrix is considered singular (computing determinant is not robust enough)? Ideally, it would be nice if there's a way to use a `try` `except` block to catch NumPy's singular array error.

How would I do this? The NumPy error given at the terminal is:

```
raise LinAlgError, 'Singular matrix'
numpy.linalg.linalg.LinAlgError: Singular matrix
```

Answer (score 57, accepted):

The syntax would be like this:

```
import numpy as np

try:
    # your code that will (maybe) throw
except np.linalg.LinAlgError as err:
    if 'Singular matrix' in str(err):
        # your error handling block
    else:
        raise
```

Comment: Thanks. It's one of those head-slapping "d'oh" moments; I didn't realize we could directly use the NumPy errors in an `except` statement.

Comment: Also, is there any way to make this specific to 'Singular matrix' and not just any instance of LinAlgError?

Comment: Well, you can re-raise the caught exception if it's not that message.. see the latest edit to my answer.  This is one way to do it, I'm not sure if there is maybe a better way.

Answer (score 7):

[wim](https://stackoverflow.com/users/674039/)'s answer no longer works for current versions of NumPy (I'm using 1.13 at the time of writing). Instead do:

```
import numpy as np

try:
    # your code that will (maybe) throw
except np.linalg.LinAlgError as e:
    if 'Singular matrix' in str(e):
        # your error handling block
    else:
        raise
```

Comment: Next time feel free to just edit my answer directly (it is now updated).

Comment: I simply can't get that working. The code just throws the error, without handling the exception. Do you know if anything has changed?